# Does a customer who uses a cloud service provider with ISO27017 compliance, need their own certificate to be compliant themselves?

Tags: iso27001, iso27002

[ISO 27017](https://www.iso27001security.com/html/27017.html) advises both cloud service customers and providers. Microsoft Azure is [compliant](https://servicetrust.microsoft.com/) with ISO27017.

Let us say that a cloud service customer who uses Microsoft Azure wants to be compliant with ISO27017 - I assume that he/she is not automatically compliant with ISO27017 by virtue of Microsoft's certificate.

I am having trouble understanding the apparent dichotomy between ISO27017 being a standard regarding the relationship between cloud service customers and providers, yet each party apparently needs their own certificate.

Or do we say that there are really two certificates - one for "giving" and one for "receiving" and each party needs its own certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the overview of ISO 27017](https://www.iso27001security.com/html/27017.html):

> The standard advises both cloud service **customers** and cloud service **providers**, with the primary guidance laid out side-by-side in each section.

Thus, the standard clearly has guidances for both. Given that a cloud service provider can not fulfill the requirements on the customer  the customer clearly can not automatically be compliant just by using the right cloud provider.

This is similar to safety of a car: just because the vendor has to implement several safety measures the car is not automatically safe. It also depends on how the customer drives so there are requirements for this too.